# How i can change UserInfo in UILocalNotification?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have 6 **UILocalNotifications.
Every notification has its own "userInfo"**

1. @"1"
2. @"2"
3. @"3"
4. @"4"
5. @"5"
6. @"6"

Then i delete notification number 4, and have 5 notification:

1. @"1"
2. @"2"
3. @"3"
4. @"5"
5. @"6"

How i can change **"userInfo"** in notifications to get:

1. @"1"
2. @"2"
3. @"3"
4. @"4"
5. @"5"

Save code -

```
// Specify custom data for the notification

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i] forKey:@"notif"];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
 i = i + 1;
```

Del code -

```
if (flagTable == 1)
{
    int numberPhoto = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];
    int numPhFlag = numberPhoto;
    int i = 0;
    NSLog(@"Col notif = %d", numberPhoto);
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    while (numberPhoto == numPhFlag) {
        localNotif = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] objectAtIndex:i];
        localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
        NSString *itemDateWithFormat = [format stringFromDate:localNotif.fireDate];
        NSLog(@"remText2 %@ = fireDate2 %@", itemDateWithFormat, [appDel.fireDateArray objectAtIndex:row]);
        if ([itemDateWithFormat isEqualToString:[appDel.fireDateArray objectAtIndex:row]]) {
            NSLog(@"remText3 %@ = fireDate3 %@", itemDateWithFormat, [appDel.fireDateArray objectAtIndex:row]);
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotif];
            numPhFlag = numPhFlag - 1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    int getNot = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];
    NSLog(@"Col notif2 = %d", getNot);
}
```

I want to iterate over the notifications and replace data in its userInfo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the answer =)

```
int notifCount = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];
for (int j = 0; j < notifCount; j++) {
    UILocalNotification *notific = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] objectAtIndex:j];
    NSLog(@"notificBefore = %@ and j = %i", [notific.userInfo objectForKey:@"notif"], j+1);
    if ([notific.userInfo objectForKey:@"notif"] != [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j+1]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notific];
        NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j+1] forKey:@"notif"];
        [notific setUserInfo:infoDict];
        NSLog(@"notificEnd = %@", [notific.userInfo objectForKey:@"notif"]);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notific];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing about a UILocalNotification is the you cant edit the information of any uilocalnofication. You have to cancel it and reschedule it. So while rescheduling you'll have to use the array of the scheduled notifications that are present and reschedule (schedule a new notification and cancel the existing ones. This is something like you are replacing the notifications by cancelling and rescheduling)

```
NSArray *scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledNotifications];
i = 0;
for (UILocalNotification *notif in scheduledNotifications) {
  UILocalNotification *notifToReschedule;

  i++; 

  notifToReschedule.userInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",i];
  notifToReschedule.timeZone = notif.timeZone
  // you can use the already scheduled local notification's information to schedule another one. and cancel the one yo are iterating through. 

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notifToReschedule];

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notif];
}
```

Comment: since iOS 4.2 scheduledLocalNotifications is a read-write property, he can retrieve the array, work on it and set it back using scheduledLocalNotifications. It will automatically unscheduled old notifications and replace them by the new array